# Woocommerce - Where is the location of free shipping method?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

## Where is the location of free shipping method?

Yes, the free shipping we turn on in the settings

I mean the file in which the fields of input are stated, and so on.

I understand that the file should be of the following structure:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Method.html

---

I will be grateful...

Comment: to work with WordPress, it's usefull to have a editor that search in all files (like searching the text "WC_Shipping_Free_Shipping" for you question). If you are on Windows try Notepad++, and try also Eclipse PHP which work with Linux and Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Location:

includes/shipping/free-shipping/class-wc-shipping-free-shipping.php

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Free_Shipping.html